# Azure DeploymentGroup

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Im trying to create new Deployment Group for Dev environment but im getting error " 'powershell.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file." when try to execute the Registration script (PowerShell) in windows server with admin rights .

Attached screen shot : [Azure_Deployment_group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YBds.png) [windows_server__error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpXTX.png)

Not sure sure what is going wrong , any help please

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What troubleshooting steps have you taken?

Comment: @DanielMann - i got solution, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're missing an environment variable.
Add this to your Path environment variable: `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\`
[image]

Try the same too in case of missing an environment variable. You could also change your script to this: `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command "your command"`

Result:
[image]